# Cant completely remove view controller? Variables are saved?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

Ok, I have my VCs in a TabBarController here and I can't completely remove a view controller. I need to delete it and reinstantiate it, wipe it clean. But even after calling `removeFromSuperview`, this function (my delete function) continues to be called. I know because the console statement is printed:

```
func resetPodcastVC()
    {
        overallNavigator.selectedIndex = 1 //list view
        trackStatus = .Initializing
        urlStr = ""

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "podcast")
        var viewcontrollers = overallNavigator.viewControllers
        viewcontrollers?.removeLast()
        self.removeFromParentViewController()
        viewcontrollers?.append(vc)
        overallNavigator.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers, animated: true)
        print("delete", trackStatus)
    }
```

As you can see, I am forcefully resetting trackStatus and urlStr up at the top. But in the print statement trackStatus goes back to being `.Failed`, which is what triggered the reset func in the first place:

```
func updateLoader()
    {
        if(isSwitching)
        {
            loadMessage = "Switch tracks"
        }
        else {
            if (trackStatus == .Initializing)
            {
                loadMessage = "Initializing"
            }
            else if(trackStatus == .Buffering)
            {
                loadMessage = "Buffering"
            }
            else if(trackStatus == .Failed)
            {
                loadMessage = "Failed"

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    self.resetPodcastVC()
                }
            }
            else {
                loadMessage = "Playing"
            }
        }
```

This update func is called on a timer. The trackStatus is based on the AVPlayer Status of the last URL passed to it.

I don't know what is wrong here. After I try to completely delete this instance of the VC, after switching to the new index (index 1 is another VC), I am not able to  switch to any other index because this reset func continues to be called.

How can I completely remove this VC and reset it as new?

Comment: Where is the timer?  Timer's will prevent a VC from being released unless invalidated.

Comment: You don't need to load a new instance of the view controller; you simply need to update the data you are showing in the current one.

Comment: UITabBarController itself manages adding / removing child view controller. You just need to update data in your podcast's viewWillAppear() if you require to update any data.

Comment: in UITabBarController it is not required to remove views as it will load again even if you remove as Tabbar is used in cases to show Functionality that is always active and if you remove View tabBar will. take time to load. and its all tabBar functionality if you facing any Ram issues Don't Worry memory is released after on when Tab bar switched